# Can I inject a Java object using Spring without any xml configuration files?

Tags: java, spring

I want to inject a plain java object using Spring programmatically without using any xml configuration. Want to inject fields/methods annotated with tags Like `@EJB`, `@PostConstruct` etc. Is that possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Creating an ApplicationContext without XML (using AnnotationConfigApplicationContext)

With [AnnotationConfigApplicationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.html), you don't need any XML at all. You create the Application context programatically and either

a) manually [register annotated classes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.html#register%28java.lang.Class...%29)

```
appContext.register( MyTypeA.class,
                     MyTypeB.class,
                     MyTypeC.class );
```

b) or [scan the classpath for annotated classes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.html#scan%28java.lang.String...%29)

```
appContext.scan(
    "com.mycompany.myproject.mypackagea",
    "com.mycompany.myproject.mypackageb"
)
```

If you use one of the convenience constructors

[AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Class<?> ... annotatedClasses)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.html#AnnotationConfigApplicationContext%28java.lang.Class...%29)

or

[AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(String ... basePackages)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.html#AnnotationConfigApplicationContext%28java.lang.String...%29)

the context is created and refreshed automatically, otherwise you need to call the [refresh()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html#refresh%28%29) method manually after adding the classes or packages.

### Autowiring existing non-Spring beans (using AutowireCapableBeanFactory)

For autowiring an existing bean I think the preferred idiom is to use

```
appContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(existingBean)
```

Or, if you want more control, use

```
appContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
      .autowireBeanProperties(
          existingBean,
          autowireMode,
          // e.g. AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE 
          dependencyCheck
      )
```

For further reference, see

- [ApplicationContext.getAutowireCapeableBeanFactory()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html#getAutowireCapableBeanFactory%28%29)
- [AutowireCapeableBeanFactory.autowireBean(Object existingBean)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html#autowireBean%28java.lang.Object%29)
- [AutowireCapeableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(Object
  existingBean, int autowireMode,
  boolean dependencyCheck)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html#autowireBeanProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20boolean%29)

Comment: This is what I want. Btw, if I created the object (not by Spring), can I use Spring to inject this object the dependencies after that?

Comment: i think this one is too trivial, seems ctx.autowireBean(bean) and many more methods could do this.

Comment: @seanizer: Thanks for your response! downvote? definitely not me

Comment: I am using java based config, and one bean reads external file to create objects by class names. Objects can autowire each other. How can I register them during creation of other bean?

Comment: @VadimKirilchuk ask a new question!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can annotate any POJO with `@Component`, `@Service`, `@Controller`, or `@Respository` (depending on its responsibilities), and it becomes a spring bean. You just have to put this line into the `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.yourbasepackage" />
```

You can also use `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` instead of the xml `init-method` and `destroy-method`.

**Update:**  There is a project called spring-javaconfig. Parts of it have become part of the core spring and you can see [more details here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java). In short, it allows you to use java classes instead of xml for configuring your beans.

Comment: What is the difference with <context:annotation-config> ?

Comment: spring-javaconfig docs - http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java

Comment: `context:annotation-config` wouldn't work. It detects annotations on existing beans.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation around annotation-based Spring configuration can be found [**here**](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config). You will need a minimal amount of XML, so that Spring knows to look for annotation-based configuration:

```
<context:component-scan base-package=".." />
```

Once that is done, you can use the `@Autowired` annotation to set up your beans.

Comment: What is the difference with <context:component-scan> ?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? **annotation-config** *`<context:annotation-config/>` only looks for annotations on beans in the same application context in which it is defined.*

**component-scan**
*In the example above, the `com.acme package` will be scanned, looking for any `@Component`-annotated classes, and those classes will be registered as Spring bean definitions within the container.*